# Parsing already parsed results with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have a question with using python and beautifulsoup.

My end result program basically fills out a form on a website and brings me back the results which I will eventually output to an lxml file. I'll be taking the results from https://interactive.web.insurance.ca.gov/survey/survey?type=homeownerSurvey&event=HOMEOWNERS and I want to get a list for every city all into some excel documents.

Here is my code, I put it on pastebin: 
http://pastebin.com/bZJfMp2N

MY RESULTS ARE ALMOST GOOD :D except now I'm getting            355 for my "correct value" instead of 355, for example. I want to parse that and only show the number, you will see when you put this into python.

However, anything I have tried does NOT work, there is no way I can parse that values_2 variable because the results are in bs4.element.resultset when I think i need to parse a string. Sorry if I am a noob, I am still learning and have worked very long on this program.

Would anyone have any input? Anything would be appreciated! I've read up that my results are in a list or something and i can't parse lists? How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code:

```
__author__ = 'kennytruong'
#THE PROBLEM HERE IS TO PARSE THE RESULTS PROPERLY!!


import urllib.parse, urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://interactive.web.insurance.ca.gov/survey/survey?type=homeownerSurvey&event=HOMEOWNERS"



#Goes through these locations, strips the whitespace in the string and creates a list that starts at every new line
LOCATIONS = '''
ALAMEDA ALAMEDA
'''.strip().split('\n') #strip() basically removes whitespaces
print('Available locations to choose from:', LOCATIONS)


INSURANCE_TYPES = '''
HOMEOWNERS,CONDOMINIUM,MOBILEHOME,RENTERS,EARTHQUAKE - Single Family,EARTHQUAKE - Condominium,EARTHQUAKE - Mobilehome,EARTHQUAKE - Renters
'''.strip().split(',') #strips the whitespaces and starts a newline of the list every comma
print('Available insurance types to choose from:', INSURANCE_TYPES)


COVERAGE_AMOUNTS = '''
15000,25000,35000,50000,75000,100000,150000,200000,250000,300000,400000,500000,750000
'''.strip().split(',')
print('All options for coverage amounts:', COVERAGE_AMOUNTS)


HOME_AGE = '''
New,1-3 Years,4-6 Years,7-15 Years,16-25 Years,26-40 Years,41-70 Years
'''.strip().split(',')
print('All Home Age Options:', HOME_AGE)




def get_premiums(location, coverage_type, coverage_amt, home_age):
    formEntries = {'location':location,
                   'coverageType':coverage_type,
                   'coverageAmount':coverage_amt,
                   'homeAge':home_age}
    inputData = urllib.parse.urlencode(formEntries)
    inputData = inputData.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request(URL, inputData)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    responseData = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, "html.parser")
    parseResults = soup.find_all('tr', {'valign':'top'})


    for eachthing in parseResults:
        parse_me = eachthing.text
        name = re.findall(r'[A-z].+', parse_me) #find me all the words that start with a cap, as many and it doesn't matter what kind.
        # the . for any character and + to signify 1 or more of it.
        values = re.findall(r'\d{1,10}', parse_me) #find me any digits, however many #'s long as long as btwn 1 and 10
        values_2 = eachthing.find_all('div', {'align':'right'})

        print('raw code for this part:\n' ,eachthing, '\n')
        print('here is the name: ', name[0], values)
        print('stuff on sheet 1- company name:', name[0], '- Premium Price:', values[0], '- Deductible', values[1])
        print('but here is the correct values - ', values_2) #NEEDA STRIP THESE VALUES
#        print(type(values_2))  DOING SO GIVES ME <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>, NEEDA PARSE bs4.element type
#       values_3 = re.split(r'\d', values_2)
#        print(values_3)   ANYTHING LIKE THIS WILL NOT WORK BECAUSE I BELIEVE RESULTS ARENT STRING
        print('\n\n')









def main():
    for location in LOCATIONS: #seems to be looping the variable location in LOCATIONS - each location is one area
        print('Here are the options that you selected: ', location, "HOMEOWNERS", "150000", "New", '\n\n')
        get_premiums(location, "HOMEOWNERS", "150000", "New")  #calls function get_premiums and passes parameters






if __name__ == "__main__": #this basically prevents all the indent level 0 code from getting executed, because otherwise the indent level 0 code gets executed regardless upon opening
    main()
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the code here, not on pastebin.

Comment: TMI = Too many issues. Please try fixing them one by one. Start with `[A-z].+` regex - it is not doing what you believe it does.

Comment: @stribzhev I'm not sure if there i sany other option. I need to find that seperately or else it doesn't run, or outputs spaces.

Comment: @nhahtdh I've put it in a code block, sorry!

Comment: `values_2` is the result of a call to a method named `find_all()`.  Of course it is not a single string.  It's a set of all _div_-Elements and those are of type `bs4.element.Tag` and have the mostly the same methods as the `BeautifulSoup` object. So you can search for subelements from each of it. Or take their `text` attribute and use string operations on them.

Comment: @BlackJack how would I take the text attribute of the bs4 object? Everytime I try to get anything out of the bs4 object it doesn't recognize it and says Resultset error... :(

Comment: @BlackJack I'm getting a typeError if I use values_3 = re.split(r'\d', values_2)

Comment: Not _the_ object but the _objects_ (plural) — a `ResultSet` contains more than one object, because `find_all()` can have more than one result because it finds _all_ matching elements. The `ResultSet` itself doesn't have a `text` attribute, but the contained elements have. You have to iterate over the elements to get the text. And of course you can't use `re.split()` on an object that isn't a kind of string.

Comment: @BlackJack did you mean like this? 

for somevariable in soup.findAll(attrs={'valign':'top'}):

        stuff = somevariable.text

        x = re.findall(r'[ ]', stuff)

Comment: what would i put inside the parenthesis? Because if i do r'[\d*]' it gets most of the numbers but not the N/A. How would i make it so that it could take the N/A and also a number?

Comment: I wouldn't search for texts at all except for the known text in the first cell (header) of that table. If you have the table element then you know where to find which information because the data is _structured_ in that table. No need to resort to techniques like regex one would need for more unstructured plain text data.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've gotten it.